# Text justification C language

Tags: c, text, alignment

I have to solve a problem that involves left justification string length and leading zeros.

I have the following table :

1. BEGIN
2. CLOSE
3. CONCATENATE
4. DELETE
5. END
6. INITIALIZE
7. PRINT
8. WRITE

This is produced by a simple program.
My problem is to find out how to convert it like that :

[image]

It has to be perfectly aligned.

I have to use left justification and not the "tab" ( \t ).
Also, i have to calculate the string length. My code so far is the following :

```
 int i;

 int long temp;

 char a = 'a';

 char command[][12]= {

"BEGIN", "CLOSE", "CONCATENATE", "DELETE",
"END" , "INITIALIZE", "PRINT", "WRITE"

};

int main()

{

printf("a/a \tCommand \tLength\n");

for (i=0 ; i<8 ;i++){

    temp = strlen(command[i]);

    printf("%c. %10s %ld \n",a, command[i], temp);

    a++;

}

printf("\n");

return 0;

}
```

I am trying to add an integer instead of the number ( 10 ) in the printf but i don't know if it is the right solution.

For example something like this:

```
    printf("%c. %10s %%dld \n",a, command[i], integer,  temp);
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes. My task is to modify the output in the given one. And for my formatting purposes i will need to find information on:
left justification 
minimum string length 
and leading zeros.

Comment: And where do you expect to find the leading zeroes?

Comment: I don't know. It is just included in my question. I suppose that i will not use it in anything, but i have just to say a few words about its function. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an example of how to output what you want:

the line:

```
printf("%c. %10s %ld \n",a, command[i], temp);
```

should be written as:

```
printf("%c. %-10.10s %5.ld \n",a, command[i], temp);
```

and this line:

```
printf("%c. %10s %ld \n",a, command[i], temp);
```

should be written as:

```
printf("%c. %-10.10s %5.ld \n",a, command[i], temp);
```

Notice the '-' on the %s for left justification,

Notice the 10.10 on the %s to force the field to always to 10 characters

Notice the '5.' on the %d to force the field to always be 5 characters
(right justified)

There are other modifications for fill characters other than space, to inhibit leading 0 suppression, etc.

you may want to look here for further details:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Answer (score 2):

From printf's manual:

> The field width
>
> An optional decimal digit string (with nonzero first digit) specifying
>   a minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer characters
>   than the field width, it will be padded with spaces on the left (or
>   right, if the left-adjustment flag has been given). **Instead of a
>   decimal digit string one may write "*"** or "*m$" (for some decimal
>   integer m) **to specify that the field width is given in the next
>   argument**, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type
>   int.
>   (emphasis mine)

So you can write :

```
printf("%c. %10s %*ld \n",a, command[i], temp, integer);
```

Comment: This solution seems to work. I will test it and i will see if something else is needed. Otherwise i will check your answer as the solution. Thank you very much.